# Update table depending of column who is into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `DesignGroup` like:

```
+---------------+------------+
| DesignGroupId | ProjectKey |
+---------------+------------+
```

and other table called `Design` where I added DesignGroup ForeignKey:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| DesignKey | DesignGroupId(FK) |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

That I want to do is to insert `DesignGroupId` on `Design` table depending of his `ProjectKey`, but in order to know ProjectKey of each Design. I need to query other table:

```
SELECT  PD.ProjectKey from Design AS D 
INNER JOIN ProjectDesign AS PD ON D.DesignKey = PD.DesignKey
```

How can I perform this update?

Comment: Update?  Insert?  I'm really confused.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want to join through multiple tables for the `update`:

```
update d
    set DesignGroupId = dg.DesignGroupId
    from design d join
         ProjectDesign pd
         on d.DesignKey = pd.DesignKey join
         designgroup dg
         on dg.ProjectKey = pd.ProjectKey;
```